# Delete MySQL column index without knowing its name

Tags: mysql, sql, database, hibernate, indexing

I have an application which uses Hibernate to support Oracle and MySQL databases. After an update I have to manually delete some columns with indexes/constraints on it. These indexes have Hibernate generated random names.

In Oracle I can do this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP (column_name) CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
```

Unfortunately this isn't possible for MySQL. Is there a possibility to do something like this

```
DROP INDEX (SELECT Key_name FROM (SHOW INDEX FROM table_name WHERE Column_name = 'column_name')) ON table_name;
```

before I drop the column?

EDIT: This should work without user interaction in a SQL script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select indexes for a table form information_schema:

```
SELECT DISTINCT INDEX_NAME, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_SCHEMA FROM information_schema.STATISTICS;
```

Answer (score 1):

To get all indexes for a particular database (replace **<Database_Name>** with your database name), use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT INDEX_NAME 
FROM information_schema.STATISTICS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE '<Database_Name>';
```

To get all indexes for a table (replace **<Table_Name>** with your table name) of a particular database, use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT INDEX_NAME 
FROM information_schema.STATISTICS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE '<Database_Name>' AND 
    TABLE_NAME LIKE '<Table_Name>';
```

To get all indexes of a specific column (replace **<Column_Name>** with your column name) of a table in a particular database, use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT INDEX_NAME 
FROM information_schema.STATISTICS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE '<Database_Name>' AND
     TABLE_NAME LIKE '<Table_Name>' AND 
     COLUMN_NAME LIKE '<Column_Name>';
```

In addition to that, you may also use any Wildcard character in the LIKE operator to get specific records, like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT INDEX_NAME 
FROM information_schema.STATISTICS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE '<Database_Name>' AND 
    TABLE_NAME LIKE 'tbl_prefix_%';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to manually delete the indexes, [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)  says:

> If columns are dropped from a table, the columns are also removed from
>   any index of which they are a part. If all columns that make up an
>   index are dropped, the index is dropped as well. If you use CHANGE or
>   MODIFY to shorten a column for which an index exists on the column,
>   and the resulting column length is less than the index length, MySQL
>   shortens the index automatically.